# Do I need to sudo when running pip/easy_install?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sudo

All of the python tuts I've been reading lately tell me to do things like this:

```
pip install tornado
pip install requests
```

And every time I do this I get hit with a `permission denied` warning. But everything usually works when I `sudo`.

Is sudo required? And if so, why do so many tutorial instructions fail to mention that?

In ruby we can install using Rbenv or RVM, both of which remove the need to use `sudo`. Is there any equivalent in python? Or is it implied that you should always `sudo`?

Comment: Ahh that helps a bit, if it's a Mac thing. That explains a lot. I am install virtualenv right now and I think that might help me out with some problems.

Comment: You can use `pip install --user package`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pip` requires permission to write the libraries to whichever directory it is using. This problem occurs when you do not have permission as a user and so `pip` fails. Using `sudo` gets around this problem but is not ideal.

**You should not ever run code using sudo as you don't know what is inside the library, if it contains malicious code you could cause serious damage to your computer.**

You can fix this problem by ensuring that you have permissions to write to the directory that `pip` is set up to use.

A better alternative (as you've suggested in your comment) is to use a virtualenv, this will allow you to use `pip` without the need of `sudo`. Make sure you do not create this virtualenv using `sudo` though as then you won't have permissions to write to it as a normal user.